# Plotting general number of lines from simulations in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using R I want to simulate 500 data sets and fit a glm() model on each data set. For each fitted model I want to predict over a specified range of x values, and then I want to plot the resulting predictions. I have a couple questions:

1. Should I simulate 500 data sets, each time adding the predictions as a column of a data frame, and then plot from that data frame at the end? Or should I somehow add a line to the plot after each iteration?
2. I'm assuming ggplot is much better than the base R plot() for this, and I know how to plot a few lines but I don't know how to do it in a general sense when you have too many lines to do it manually. Based on 1) , can anyone tell me how to plot many lines with ggplot?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using data structured in a list., with each simulation being stored as an element in the list. A walk-through example is below, though you may need to tweak for your data (ie, 500 colors would be nonsense, so just used here for example purposes)

Example data of 6 simulated datasets stored in a list

```
set.seed(123)

list_data <- list()
for(i in 1:6){
  df <- data.frame(x = runif(100))
  df$y <- df$x + runif(100)
  list_data[[i]] <- df
}
```

Run the models and predictions using `lapply` (storing results in a list):

```
# Run models
list_mdl <- lapply(list_data, function(x) glm(x ~ y, data = x))

# Specify desired range
specified_range <- 1:50

# Run predictions
pred_list <- lapply(list_mdl, function(mdl) 
  predict(mdl, newdata = data.frame(y = specified_range)))
```

Plot:

```
# initiate blank plot
plot(NA, xlim = range(specified_range), ylim = c(0, 100), 
     bty = "n", xlab = "x Value", ylab = "Predicted Value")

# plot lines by simulation
sapply(seq_along(pred_list), function(z) lines(pred_list[[z]], col = z))
legend("topright", paste("Simulation", seq_along(list_data)), 
       lty = 1, col = seq_along(list_data), bty = "n")
```

[image]